# Manual Deep Copy to Device in C

Tags: c, openacc, pgi

I am attempting to parallelize a program that does some image processing with openACC.  As a part of this processing I have a custom structure defined similar to:

```
typedef struct {
  RGB *image;
  double property;
} Deep;
```

Which I am accessing within an array `Deep *structPointer`.

I have come across some documents for manually copying the entire contents of `structPointer` to the GPU, which has left me with the following code.

```
  Deep *structPointer = (Deep*)
    malloc(total_size*sizeof(Deep));
  assert(structPointer);

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < total_size; i++)
  {
    structPointer[i].image = randomImage(width, height, max);
  }

    dP = acc_copyin( stuctPointer, sizeof( Deep )*total_size ); 

  for ( i=0; i < total_size; i++ ) {
   dA = acc_copyin( structPointer[i].image, sizeof(RGB)*width*height );     //device address in dA
   acc_memcpy_to_device( &dP[i].image, &dA,  sizeof(RGB*) );
  }
```

This all runs fine, until I try to run a parallel for loop  that accesses `structPointer` and modifies the `property` attributes of the members of the array based on the contents of `RGB *image`.

Pseudo code:

```
#pragma acc parallel loop copyin(inputImage[0:width*height], width, height)
for (i = 0; i < total_size; i++) {
  computeProperty(input_image, structPointer+i, width, height)
}

inline void compProperty (const RGB *A, Deep *B, int width, int height)
{
   B->property = 10;
}
```

I get:

> call to cuStreamSynchronize returned error 700: Illegal address during
>   kernel execution

The output of `cuda-memcheck` is:

```
> ========= CUDA-MEMCHECK image2.ppm is a PPM file 256 x 256 image, max value= 255
> ========= Program hit CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_CONTEXT (error 201) due to "invalid device context" on CUDA API call to cuCtxAttach.
> =========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
> =========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/libcuda.so (cuCtxAttach + 0x156) [0x13fc36]
> =========     Host Frame:./genimg_acc [0x13639]
> =========
> ========= Program hit CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS (error 700) due to "an illegal memory access was encountered" on CUDA API call to
> cuStreamSynchronize. call to cuStreamSynchronize returned error 700:
> Illegal address during kernel execution
> =========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
> =========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/libcuda.so (cuStreamSynchronize + 0x13d) [0x149a9d]
> =========     Host Frame:./genimg_acc [0x15856]
> =========
> ========= Program hit CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS (error 700) due to "an illegal memory access was encountered" on CUDA API call to
> cuCtxSynchronize.
> =========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
> =========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/libcuda.so (cuCtxSynchronize + 0x127) [0x13ee37]
```

Note that the program runs when compiled without openACC and will process correctly when run in a single thread.

Comment: Do you really mean to be using `&inputImage[j]` in the assignment to `f`? Don't you want the value of `inputImage[j]` not the address?

Comment: That is just pseudoCode in lieu of pasting the entire procedure.  If the procedure would help I can expand on this, but essentially this is what it is doing.

Comment: You could try pasting that. It's possible your procedure is what is corrupting something.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found a reference for [OpenACC Deep Copying](https://cug.org/proceedings/cug2014_proceedings/includes/files/pap122.pdf) which may be what you're looking at already based on the `Deep` name. Looking at *Figure 9* on page 7, they give you an example of doing a deep copy on a structure containing both scalars and pointers.

One must use the pointer returned by `acc_copyin` to access the array of structures within the parallelized code--namely `dP` instead of `structPointer`. The following code should fix the problem.

```
#pragma acc parallel loop copyin(inputImage[0:width*height], width, height)
for (i = 0; i < total_size; i++) {
  computeProperty(input_image, dP+i, width, height)
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like there is just an `acc_copyin()` and `acc_copyout()`. I'm looking over the spec for OpenACC to see if I can give you any other ideas.

Comment: I appreciate the effort.  Thank you!

Comment: Oh I just realized the problem... well at least a big one. You need to be using `dP` not `structPointer` in your parallelized code.

Comment: That has fixed it. Thank you!  The source I was using had listed that `structPointer` was "now available on the device".  Update your answer and I will accept it.